# Why so many wires in my old light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

My old light fixture not working so I took it apart and will get a replacement.

Then I noticed so many wires!

[image: fixture taken apart]

Then I cut all the wires and now have this:

[image: wires]

After I cut it, I noticed other light fixtures nearby are not working..

I plan to get a replacement fixture, but a different type, I'm not sure how I would connect these wires, as there's 3 sets of each except brown.

Edit:
Added photo of bottom part where brown connects
[image: -]

Comment: Now you know why so many wires, they go to other fixtures.  Nice of you to take a before picture, most people don't and expect us to help with unknown connections.  Just connect same as before.  You did turn off the power before cutting I hope, that looks like 220v and hurts a lot more than our 120v.

Comment: which country is that ? we have black+white+bare

Comment: regroup the wires in a few multi-hole wago level connectors and things will be back to normal.

Comment: The single brown is a bit odd, but probably there is another junction box close by.

Comment: @Ruskes  That looks like the newer UK/Europe colours.  Blue is neutral, brown is hot.  Think older colours use black for neutral, red for hot.

Comment: @crip659 thanks, yes the brown connects to another part, I took photo again.

Comment: @Ruskes Hong Kong

Comment: @crip659 Yep, turned off mains power for safety. I'm worried if I buy different light fixture, it may not be the same, the brown connects to a thing called a ballast (which I saw from previous photo), not sure if the new fixture will have as not thinking of getting a fluorescent light fixture

Comment: Thank you ............ Post new post when you know the type of new light

Comment: @Ruskes "we" in an internationally used forum... very fine.

Comment: Most simple light fixtures will just connect brown to to brown and blue to blue.  Lights don't really care if the wires are mixed up, but there is some safety to have hots away from fingers.  Most good fixtures should come with instructions for wiring.

Comment: @crip659 - they've just, in effect, brought [most of] the rose connections below the ceiling - I do wonder where the other lives are, though. Feels like some kind of hybrid connection going on. I'd be inclined to look up into the ceiling to figure out what else is up there, & perhaps re-joint it in a more common manner. It's like they only brought down the switched live… but paralleled the rest. Very odd.

Comment: Ballast is only needed for fluorescent.  If you get any other kind of fixture, you don't need or want it.  There are, e.g. LED replacement bulbs that fit in a fluorescent fixture and bypass the ballast, but these can be problematic, so it's better if possible to remove it entirely.

Answer (score 18):

They are using your light fixture as a junction box for other light fixtures. Now that you've cut the wires, the other lights aren't working. If you get a similar fixture, you'll have to group those wires back together. If you get different type, you might have to add a junction box.

Answer (score 4):

You say you are in Hong Kong, I am in the UK. I know Hong Kong was until relatively recently a British colony and I know they use British sockets but I do not know to what extent current Hong Kong practices differ from current British practices.

The colour code of those wires presumably follows IEC standards, that is Brown is Live, Blue is neutral and green/yellow is earth. I'm not aware of any other commonly used scheme that uses those colours.

---

> there's 3 sets of each except brown.

A light switch works by interrupting the live connection to the light.

If you are wiring a pure lighting circuit* with single wires in conduit, then that natural way to do it is to take the permanent lives to the switches, the neutrals to the lights and then run a switched live wire from the switch to the light.

Under British regulations at least it is expected that you take an earth connection to every "point and accessory" on the circuit, even if the equipment currently installed there does not require earthing.

So it's perfectly normal on an installation in conduit to see multiple neutrals and multiple earths, but only a single live at a light fitting.

If cables are used rather than single wires, then this isn't really practical, so there has to be a junction somewhere, either the supply live and neutral are taken to the light fitting and then a cable carring permanent live and switched live drops down to the light, or the supply live and neutral are taken to the switch and then a cable brings switched live and neutral up to the light.

Connections should be in a suitable enclosure, but in the real world that doesn't always happen. All too often in the UK you see a terminal block stuffed up in the ceiling behind some fancy light fitting that didn't have enough room to properly acommodate the connections internally.

Where things unfortunately can get tricky on a replacement job is that while the old flourescent fittings had a load of wiring room and it was possible to bring the cables in almost anywhere, many modern fittings are far more cramped, so some re-working may be needed to make the wiring work with a modern fitting. It's difficult to advise exactly how best to do this, without seeing more detail of the fixed wiring and the new fitting, and also knowing what products are on the market where you live.

* In the USA it is the norm to mix lighting and sockets on the same circuit, in the UK it's the norm to keep them separate. I don't know what the situation is in Hong Kong but I suspect Hong Kong practices are closer to British than to American practices.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing is, the wires are all colour coded, so they can't get mixed up. For now, if you simply used connector blocks for each of the colours, the other lights will work again.

When you do connect a new light in, be sure to connect all the colours the same, together and to the new fitting and all will work and be safe.

Why so many wires? Because some will feed other lights (possibly a fan). The brown is the one which will go to the switch for that particular light only, but disconnecting the other wires has broken the circuits to other fitments.