# How should I install my new light fixture?

Tags: light

Following on my other thread:
[Why so many wires in my old light fixture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/259875/why-so-many-wires-in-my-old-light-fixture)

[image: new light fixture]
I have bought a new light fixture today and this fixture has 2 wires only.. Brown and blue. I bought one of those Electrical Wire Connector Self Locking Clips so I can connect my wires together.

Pic of original [non-standard] junction block.

[image]

I assume I connect brown with the only brown cable I have, and then with the blue, do I connect all 3 blue wires together? Or just 1?
Leave the earth cables out as no where to connect them to?
Thanks

Comment: Whereabout in the world are you? How was the old light fixture connected?

Comment: How about a picture of the wires going into the wall or junction box.

Comment: @brhans Hong Kong, please refer to my old thread. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/259875/why-so-many-wires-in-my-old-light-fixture

Comment: I replaced the pic of a bunch of loose wires with the one of the original terminal block. The upside of this setup is you can just put all the connections into a similar piece of junction block & wire the new brown & blue to the opposite side, matching colours. You could even re-use the original terminal block, if you kept it. It's only held in place by a small metal tab that is screwed into the lower centre, otherwise empty, terminal & was the earth connection for the old fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Following my answer to the other question, connect *all* the blues together (use a connector block). *All* the earths (yellow/green) - but they needn't be connected to the new fitting, as there's no place for that earth, and the brown to the new brown. That way, all the lights will still work.

Turn off the power before trying this, and make sure all the wires are safe inside the fitting - they may need shortening.

Answer (score 0):

All blue together, might need an extra piece of blue connected to the three blues.

All the earth wires connected together.

It is the same as your old light for connections.

Will need to strip the insulation off the ends.